Should I receive an extra letter of recommendation from a non-PhD researcher?
I'm seeking some advice about getting a fourth recommender. I'm applying to PhD programs in statistics and biostatistics. I asked my 3 recommenders, a PI and two former professors, back in June and they've all gotten their recommendations submitted.
Since June, though, I started a new position doing remote, part-time research in a lab that's related to my applied interest. I've been learning a lot and it's been a meaningful experience so far, but I've only been doing it for 3-4 months and part time at that. I've worked with the MS-level lab manager primarily and haven't really interacted with the MD PI at all. That said, the manager has several publications with the lab and indicated he would write a strong letter.
Would you all recommend getting a recommendation from the lab manager as a fourth recommendation to speak to this experience? I think it could help my application, but it could also dilute the current recommendations.
Thank you.

A letter from someone that doesn't have a doctorate is much less valuable than otherwise. A good letter needs to be able to accurately predict your success in doctoral study, research, and a career in field.
If a place asks for three, I'd send the best three available to me. But, you don't say how much contact you have had with the two "professors". If it is just a course in which you did well, then they might not be able to make the required prediction honestly.
You might suggest to the fourth person that you might want a recommendation at some future point and leave it there for now.

Yes, the two professors I took classes with, though I also spent a lot of time in office hours. Is it detrimental to send four letters if the guidelines are, say, "minimum 3" but don't discourage more?

My assumption would be that an additional positive recommendation would not be detrimental, and would very possibly be a helpful tie breaker if you are fairly evenly matched with other applicants.
